# Save space in flip card hover for multiple classes

Tags: css

I have this multiple flip cards in carousel format for so each time you hover on a card that I named event1, event2 and event3 to differentiate each event it will flip the code below works but I want to save space on my css file. This is the code that I am trying build

```
.event1:hover .flip-card-inner {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.event2:hover .flip-card-inner {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

 .event3:hover .flip-card-inner {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
```

I have tried to do these

```
.event1:hover, .event2:hover, .event2:hover, .flip-card-inner {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

but it flips in an awkward manner, this is the html for each card of events that  I added

```
 <div class="item">
     <div class="flip-card event3">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">   
                <div class="card__img card__img--airshow"> </div>   
                    <span class="information">
                        <p class="card__text"> Event Title  </p>
                    </span>
                    <p class="card__btn ctabtn">JOIN US</p>
                </div>

        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <div class="card__img card__img--airshowback"> </div>
               <p>Location</p>
               <p></p>
          <div class="hosted-cities">
             <a type="button" class="card__btn" href="" target="_blank" class="button">CHECK DETAILS</a>


           </div>
         </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: give a common class `event` to *all* of them and use `.event:hover .flip-card-inner`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a incorrect css syntax

```
.event1:hover, .event2:hover, .event2:hover, .flip-card-inner {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

You should change it to correct syntax below:

```
.event1:hover .flip-card-inner, .event2:hover .flip-card-inner, .event2:hover .flip-card-inner {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
```

In SCSS you can even write it as

```
.event1:hover, .event2:hover, .event2:hover {
   & .flip-card-inner {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }
}
```

The best way is to give a common class like `event`, so your css code will get shorter:

```
.event .flip-card-inner {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the comma after 2nd `event2:hover`

```
.event1:hover, .event2:hover, .event2:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```